# How to put gstab+ option to mingw makefile generated by qmake

Tags: qt, mingw, qmake

I am newby in Qt, and try to compile tutorial application with MinGW. The only problem, that I need to put `-gstab+` option to gcc compiler instead of `-g` option that qmake generated by default.

Currently, I select debug configuration (it add `CONFIG += debug` to the qmake command-line).

I've tried to add `CONFIG += gstab+` to the .pro file, but it does not work. qmake generates makefile.Debug file with `-g` option.

What do I make wrong? And how should it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution here http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/2412

I've added the following lines to my .pro file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += "-gstabs+"
QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG += "-gstabs+"
```